# Random number between 0 and 1 - quick little question

Tags: randomness

I know that the topic of random number has been discussed tremendous amount of times already but I have one small question.

I need to get a pseudo random number (not ungamealbe), as simply as possible. The problem is that I need the number to be either 1 or 0 and I want the value to be able to be odd or even in every loop iteration.

If I use something like:

```
while(x < 10) {
uint randomNumberBetween0And1 = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now))) % 2;
x++;
}
```

this value will be either 10 times 0 (0 in each iteration because random number is even) or 10 x 1 (because random number will be odd every single time). **How can I make the random differ between the iterations?**

Comment: Hi there. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use the `x` variable as a nonce (as well as a loop counter), and incorporate it into what you pass to the `keccak()` call.

Comment: Hey, thanks for anwser. In my case it's actually a while(true) kind of loop so I don't have x. Is there any way without the counter?

Comment: just replace x<10 with true, but don't forget a break. However, you'll have to keep the counter, but that shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while(x < 10) {
    uint rnd = uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, x)) & uint(0x1);
    x++;
}
```

or if you have a `while(true)` as you wrote above:

```
uint x = 0;
while(true) {
    uint rnd = uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, x++)) & uint(0x1);

    ...YOUR CODE HERE hopefully with a condition for break...
}
```